# Custom Case Status Publisher

Tags: visualforce, javascript, case

I'm developing a visualforce page exactly same as the standard case status publisher page.

My page works OK to publish the case comments and it updates the case status as well. However, I want to see the updated case status without reloading the parent case page.

**How can I refresh the case details view (case status especially) without reloading the whole page??**

I'm using following tag to call the action function:

```
<apex:actionFunction
       action="{!addComment}" 
       name="statusChange" 
       rerender="out" 
       oncomplete="refreshFeed();"
 />
```

Java script function is as follow:

```
function refreshFeed() { 
    Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({name : 'publisher.refresh', payload : {feed:true}}); 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done some experimenting and it looks like this works:

```
Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({name : 'publisher.refresh', payload : {feed: true, objectFields: true, objectRelatedLists: {}}});
```

I couldn't find it anywhere in the documentation, though.

Hope that helps!